# How to replace nested arrow functions in javascript for Safari compatibility?

Tags: javascript, safari

I am customizing a JavaScript visualization library and have written a small piece of code to fill an array for the hover info:

```
var text = zValues.map((zValues, i) => zValues.map((value, j) => {
  return ` ID: ${yValues[i]}<br> Tissue: ${xValues[j]}<br> Expression: ${value.toFixed(2)} ` 
 }))
```

It works for all browsers except Safari. I read that Safari does not support the arrow function, so I tried to replace this function as follows:

```
var text = zValues.map (function(zValues, i) { zValues.map (function (value, j) {
  return ` ID: ${yValues[i]}<br> Tissue: ${xValues[j]}<br> Expression: ${value.toFixed(2)} ` 
 });});
```

This does not give any error, but leads to an empty 'text' array. How can I fix the problem?

Comment: You need a `return`

Comment: if you really think es6 is not supported then use some Transpiler to es5 like babel

Comment: @Pointy: I tried this { zValues.map (return function (value, j) ... }) but this gives an syntax error.

Comment: https://babeljs.io/repl/

Comment: @sumeet kumar: Safari does definitely not support the arrow function, at least not 9.1.3 that I am running. Thanks for the tip with babel, I just tried now it works:o)

Comment: so just paste your code in babel and it will compile your es6 code to es5 code which should be supported by safari

Comment: Have you considered just using Babel in your project?

Comment: I didn't know about Babel before, but will use it from now on it's a great tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrow functions with just a single expression statement in the body have an implicit return. Functions created with `function` *never* have an implicit return (unless you count `undefined` I guess), so you need to explicitly return your arrow function expressions:

```
var text = zValues.map (function(zValues, i) { return zValues.map (function (value, j) {
  return ` ID: ${yValues[i]}<br> Tissue: ${xValues[j]}<br> Expression: ${value.toFixed(2)} ` 
 });});
```

(You already had the `return` on the innermost result expression.)

Comment: Why would arrow funcs be supported if template literals are?

Comment: @JonasW. Steve would have wanted it that way.